# How to bind C-i as different from TAB?

Tags: key-bindings, keymap, control-characters

I want to make `Control-i` perform `indent-region` (basically since Xcode has built that muscle memory already).

I realise that `Control-i` and `tab` are indistinguishable in the Ascii sense, but they are in the keycode sense.

I've tried the obvious:

```
(global-unset-key (kbd "C-i"))
(global-set-key (kbd "C-i") 'indent-region)
```

to no avail - pressing `Control-i` still just does whatever the `tab` key does in the current context. Is there anything I can do to help Emacs treat the tab button differently to `Control-i`?

*Update:* I guess an equivalent outcome would be achieved by being able to remap what a `tab`/`Control-i` press does when a region is selected.

Comment: Is this from a GUI frame or a terminal frame? I don't know if you can override it for a terminal.

Comment: Good Q, GUI frame usually, but I do remote into servers and use emacs in a terminal sometimes (with a git-shared emacs.d of course :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I don't think that this can be achieved from a terminal, but in GUI mode you could try this:

```lisp
(define-key input-decode-map [?\C-i] [C-i])
(global-set-key (kbd "<C-i>") 'indent-region)
```

I do the same thing with `C-m` so that it can be distinguished from `RET`

**EDIT:**

The following should work whether you are in GUI or TTY mode:

```lisp
;; Unbind <C-i> from the TAB key and bind it to indent-region.
;; Since TAB and <C-i> cannot be differentiated in TTY emacs,
;; the workaround is to conditionally bind TAB to indent-region
;; when there is an active region selected.
(if (window-system)
    ;; IF we are not in a TTY, unbind C-i from TAB
    (progn
      (define-key input-decode-map [?\C-i] [C-i])
      ;; ... and remap it to indent-region
      (global-set-key (kbd "<C-i>") 'indent-region))
  ;; ELSE IF we are in a TTY, create a replacement for TAB
  (defun my/tab-replacement (&optional START END)
    (interactive "r")
    (if (use-region-p)
        ;; IF active region, use indent-region
        (indent-region START END)
      ;; ELSE IF no active region, use default tab command
      (indent-for-tab-command)))
  ;; Bind our quick-and-dirty TAB replacement to the TAB key
  (global-set-key (kbd "TAB") 'my/tab-replacement))
```

It is not pretty, but it seems to do the job.  I welcome any refinements or edits to this code as necessary.

Comment: Works perfectly! ++ would buy an emacs stackexchange again :)

Comment: Only minor problem I just thought of is that now we can bring up a terminal emacsclient against an Emacs that was started with a window system (which I do sometimes). If I don't see any delay I'll just use the tab-replacement func in all cases.

Comment: I just want to add that the `<C-i>` and `[C-i]` could have been an arbitrary identifier, like `<foobar>` and `[foobar]`, and it would still work; just don't call it `tab` or `backspace`

Comment: I have added edited code piece on your answer into `.emacs` file but both `TAB` and `C-i` is remapped :-( @nispio

Comment: @alper, Most likely this means that `(window-system)` returned `nil` at the time your `.emacs` was loaded.  This could be because you are running a non-graphical instance of Emacs, or because you are running an Emacs daemon.

Comment: Yes nice catch, I am exactly running Emacs as daemon. Is there any way to maintain your answer by keeping Emacs running as daemon?

Comment: There's actually a bug in emacs regarding names like `[C-i]`. (though it's mostly just visual and won't really affect anything). -- 
ctrl+left is `[C-left]`, and displayed as "C-<left>". But `[C-i]` becomes `<C-i>`, because it expects the key name to be >1 char long, and doesn't see `C-` as a modifier here.
so: `[C-M-i]` will be displayed as "C-<M-i>" 

Answer (score 19):

### GUI frames

In GUI frames (whether X11, Windows, OSX, …), Emacs reads the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key as the `tab` function key. However, because the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key on terminals traditionally sends the `^I` ([Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character)+I) character, Emacs translates the `tab` function key into the Control+I character (character 9), which is displayed as `TAB`. This translation is done via [`function-key-map`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Translation-Keymaps.html#index-local_002dfunction_002dkey_002dmap).

A similar translation happens with some other function keys. (<kbd>Backspace</kbd> and <kbd>Delete</kbd> are a [thorny case](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/DEL-Does-Not-Delete.html#DEL-Does-Not-Delete) which I will not discuss in detail here.)

```
Function key    Translated to character         Notes
                Number  Name  Decomposition
backspace       127     DEL   Ctrl+?            May be translated to C-h instead
tab               9     TAB   Ctrl+I
linefeed         10     LFD   Ctrl+J            Few keyboards have this key
return           13     RET   Ctrl+M
escape           27     ESC   Ctrl+[
```

If you want to separate <kbd>Tab</kbd> from <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> altogether, remove the binding from `function-key-map`:

```
(define-key function-key-map [tab] nil)
```

However this is not very useful, because entries in `function-key-map` are overridden by bindings in mode-specific keymaps or in the global map. So if you want to define a different binding for `tab`, just do it (in Elisp, not interactively, because the key reading prompt applies the `function-key-map` translation so you'd end up rebinding `TAB` and not `tab`):

```
(global-set-key [tab] '…)
(define-key some-mode-map [tab] '…)
```

All standard modes that modify the action of the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key do it by modifying the `TAB` key, which is a nickname for the `C-i` character generated by the key combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>. If you want standard bindings to apply to `tab` rather than `C-i`, leave `function-key-map` and mode keymaps alone, and instead redirect <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> to a different key.

```
(define-key input-decode-map [(control ?i)] [control-i])
(define-key input-decode-map [(control ?I)] [(shift control-i)])
(define-key some-mode-map [control-i] '…)
```

Now Emacs will report <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> as “`<control-i>` (translated from `TAB`)”. This isn't pretty, but it's unavoidable: the pretty-printing of character 9 as `TAB` is built into the Emacs source code.

### Terminal frames

In terminal frames, the problem is harder and often impossible. Terminals don't transmit keys, they transmit characters (more precisely, in fact, they transmit bytes). The <kbd>Tab</kbd> key is transmitted as the tab character — which is Control+I, same as what the key combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> generates. Function keys that have no corresponding character (such as cursor keys) are transmitted as escape sequences, i.e. sequences of characters beginning with `ESC` = Control+[ (which is why Emacs defines <kbd>escape</kbd> as a prefix key — `ESC` has to be a prefix). See [How do keyboard input and text output work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116629/how-do-keyboard-input-and-text-output-work/116630#116630) for more background.

There are a few terminals that can be configured to send different key sequences for function keys, but not many. Both [LeoNerd's libtermkey/libtickit](http://www.leonerd.org.uk/hacks/fixterms/) and [Thomas Dickey's xterm](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-Alt-and-Meta-Keys) (since version 216) support this. In Xterm, the feature is optional and activated through the `modifyOtherKeys` resource. However, I don't know of any popular terminal emulator other than xterm that supports this, in particular the many emulators built on [libvte](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=477068). Some terminal emulators let you do this manually through a user-defined correspondence from keychords to escape sequences.

This mechanism allows many key combinations to be distinguished, not just tab/C-i, return/C-m and escape/C-[. See [Problems with keybindings when using terminal](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/1020/problems-with-keybindings-when-using-terminal/13957#13957) for a more detailed description.

The basic xterm feature is supported since Emacs 24.4. However the fundamentals (in particular <kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>Return</kbd>, <kbd>Escape</kbd>, <kbd>Backspace</kbd>) still send the traditional control characters, because that's what applications expect. There is a mode where <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>letter</kbd> sends an escape sequence instead of the control character. So to distinguish the function keys from the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> combinations on Emacs 24.4, modify its support for `modifyOtherKeys` to use this mode by setting the resource to 2 instead of 1.

```
;; xterm with the resource ?.VT100.modifyOtherKeys: 2
;; GNU Emacs >=24.4 sets xterm in this mode and define
;; some of the escape sequences but not all of them.
(defun character-apply-modifiers (c &rest modifiers)
  "Apply modifiers to the character C.
MODIFIERS must be a list of symbols amongst (meta control shift).
Return an event vector."
  (if (memq 'control modifiers) (setq c (if (or (and (<= ?@ c) (<= c ?_))
                                                (and (<= ?a c) (<= c ?z)))
                                            (logand c ?\x1f)
                                          (logior (lsh 1 26) c))))
  (if (memq 'meta modifiers) (setq c (logior (lsh 1 27) c)))
  (if (memq 'shift modifiers) (setq c (logior (lsh 1 25) c)))
  (vector c))
(defun my-eval-after-load-xterm ()
  (when (and (boundp 'xterm-extra-capabilities) (boundp 'xterm-function-map))
    ;; Override the standard definition to set modifyOtherKeys to 2 instead of 1
    (defun xterm-turn-on-modify-other-keys ()
      "Turn the modifyOtherKeys feature of xterm back on."
      (let ((terminal (frame-terminal)))
        (when (and (terminal-live-p terminal)
                   (memq terminal xterm-modify-other-keys-terminal-list))
          (send-string-to-terminal "\e[>4;2m" terminal))))
    (let ((c 32))
      (while (<= c 126)
        (mapc (lambda (x)
                (define-key xterm-function-map (format (car x) c)
                  (apply 'character-apply-modifiers c (cdr x))))
              '(;; with ?.VT100.formatOtherKeys: 0
                ("\e\[27;3;%d~" meta)
                ("\e\[27;5;%d~" control)
                ("\e\[27;6;%d~" control shift)
                ("\e\[27;7;%d~" control meta)
                ("\e\[27;8;%d~" control meta shift)
                ;; with ?.VT100.formatOtherKeys: 1
                ("\e\[%d;3~" meta)
                ("\e\[%d;5~" control)
                ("\e\[%d;6~" control shift)
                ("\e\[%d;7~" control meta)
                ("\e\[%d;8~" control meta shift)))
        (setq c (1+ c)))))
  (define-key xterm-function-map "")
  t)
(eval-after-load "xterm" '(my-eval-after-load-xterm))
```

Comment: When you say "Emacs 24.24" do you mean "Emacs 24.4"?

Comment: @tarsius A comment in the code that's copied from my init file says “24.4”, so I think that's correct, and “24.24” in the text that I wrote for this answer was a typo for “24.4”.

Comment: I think this is the better answer.

Comment: Just to expand on the topic of terminal emulators and rebinding C-i to another key sequence, both KDE's Konsole (GNU/linux) and Powertoys (windows) can do that in a few clicks in the settings.