# emacs on terminal does not recognise option as alt-key on mac

Tags: osx, terminal-emacs, input-method

I am on a mac and I am running emacs 24.4.1, but I have the same problem also with 22.1.1. When I open mac on a terminal on the remote host, it does not recognise option key (alt) like the meta key. I have modified the `.emacs` in the following way

```
(setq mac-option-key-is-meta nil
      mac-command-key-is-meta t
      mac-command-modifier 'meta
      mac-option-modifier 'none)
```

so I have tried to change the meta key to command, but also in this case the meta key doest work .  This only work on the X version of emacs (when I open emacs in a new window), both with the option as meta key that as command as meta key. This is a problem I have with emacs in the terminal-only.

Now I don't know how to run commands in emacs! is there any keybinding I can use?

Comment: Possibly related: [Problems with keybindings when using terminal](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/1020/problems-with-keybindings-when-using-terminal).

Comment: I don't recognise those variables and can't find documentation for them.  Have you tried `set-keyboard-coding-system' ?

Comment: I believe that's the "problem" with the terminal. You need to open its keyboard settings and check the corresponding option. I don't remember off the top of my head what it's called, but it's not difficult to find either.

Comment: @wvxvw it is what you say: in terminal > preference > keyboard > there is the option 'use option as meta-key'. It works! thank you

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is a setting in Terminal.

In Terminal 2.5.1 the option is set differently than in the above comments:

In the main Terminal menu, choose "Preferences" to open a dialog. Click the "Profiles" icon in the top of the dialog.

In the Profiles section, make sure there is a check in the checkbox called "Use Option as Meta key."

Answer (score 15):

I solve the problem with answer of ohruunuruus. 
Maybe post a snapshot will be more easy to understand.
[image]

Comment: How does this answer the question? Please explain. Just circling part of a screenshot does not answer the question well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using iTerm2 and find out that setting the `Option` key to `Esc+` helps.

[image]