# Why is my C-; being captured as C-_? How to fix it?

Tags: key-bindings

I'm trying to figure out why emacs is capturing C-; as C-_. I checked it using log-commands but also in a completely clean configuration I can open a file and it says "No further undo information" when I press it.

I'm using an abnt2 layout keyboard. Maybe that's it? How do I fix it?

Comment: Are you using the terminal? Different terminals are known to have some issues with certain key bindings. Try using the graphical emacs and see if the same problem occurs.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/14000/why-doesnt-c-c-or-c-work-in-a-terminal-emulator-os-x-terminal-i?rq=1) SO answer for more details on terminal incompatibilities. Hopefully it will set you along the right path.

Comment: Yes, are you using terminal mode (`emacs -nw`)? And do you see the problem when you start Emacs without your init file (`emacs -Q` or `emacs -Q -nw`)?

Comment: On what operating system? In what environment (graphical or terminal)? If it's a terminal, with which terminal emulator? What about other C-character combinations?

Comment: I'm using terminal Emacs through a ssh connection using Putty. Yeah, I know, weird working conditions. Turns out it's a terminal limitation. I wonder what can be done in this case?