# how to substitute SUPER keybindings in Emacs terminal mode?

Tags: key-bindings, osx, terminal-emacs, term

In GNU Emacs GUI, I use the Mac Command key <kbd>⌘</kbd> as `super`: `(setq mac-command-modifier 'super)`

However, the <kbd>⌘</kbd> key [does not send input to Terminal or iTerm2](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/14029/making-command-act-as-super-in-iterm2). Given this, is there a way to simulate the `super` key and still access my Emacs `super` keybindings from within terminal mode?

If I'm trying to do keybinding `(kbd "s-s")`, for instance, can I tell Emacs to look for some substitute, like maybe <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>k</kbd> or something? Or even a key-chord like `(key-chord-define-global "SS" 'super-modifier)`?

Note: I also have keybindings that combine `super` with other modifier keys, e.g. `(kbd "s-S-k")`, i.e. <kbd>⌘⇧K</kbd>.

Comment: [You can configure individual combinations in iTerm2](https://iterm2.com/documentation-preferences.html). (See http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/1020/problems-with-keybindings-when-using-terminal/13957#13957) Does that not work for Super+key combinations?

Comment: I don't want to configure 52 key combinations; I want to remap Super itself.

Comment: I know, but AFAIK this isn't possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply the Super modifier with the sequence `C-x @ s (event-apply-super-modifier)` to the next key sequence/input event.

See that functions description, other modifiers with `C-x @ C-h` and the info page ["(emacs) Modifier Keys"](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Modifier-Keys.html)