# emacs -nw set key-bindings similar to those of emacs-gui

Tags: key-bindings, emacs-nox

In `emacs -nw`, many shortcuts are bound to something different from the "classical" emacs-gui. For instance:

- `\C-_` is bound to DEL  (classically it is undo)
- `backspace` is `\C-h` thus opens help  (classically: DEL)
- `\C-backspace` is bound to DEL  (classically: backward-kill-word)

I'd like to retrieve the ones I'm used to, so
following [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/DEL-Does-Not-Delete.html) and [that](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/352/how-to-override-major-mode-bindings), I've started this init file:

```lisp
(normal-erase-is-backspace-mode 1)  ; fix backspace and del keys
(global-set-key "\C-_"     'undo)   ; redefine undo... doesn't work, requires a minor-mode, cf https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/352/how-to-override-major-mode-bindings
(global-set-key "\M-_"     'undo)   ; that'll do for the moment
; TODO: ctrl-backspace
;       any other?
```

But it seems I'm reinventing the wheel.

Isn't there already a solution? Probably in the form of a nox-compat-minor-mode?

Comment: "Classic" can mean different things, so that's probably not the best term to use here -- I think it could equally refer to the opposite of what you intend it to mean.

Comment: I think what you *want* is for key sequences to work the same way in a terminal as they do in GUI Emacs.  Is that correct?

Comment: (Spoiler -- most terminal emulators can't send Emacs all the key sequences that can be sent in a GUI environment.  What's actually possible will very likely depend on the particular terminal emulator you're using.)

Comment: @phils : yes, it is the key sequence of GUI emacs. I'll clarify the question.

Comment: @phils : yes, I've seen that it will depend on the terminal emulator; that's why I'm interested in a more general solution than my little hand-made fixes.

Comment: I can't provide you with a solution; but there are many Q&As on ES and SO on the general topic of Emacs keys which don't work in terminals, so I can point you in that direction for further research.  https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/18000 and its links seems like a good place to start, and https://github.com/CyberShadow/term-keys (from one of those answers) might be pretty close to what you're asking for.