# Paredit slurp hotkey doesnt work

Tags: key-bindings, paredit

I'm having a real hard time getting the paredit slurp key to work. I know it is bound to `C-)`, and by describing the `paredit-slurp-forward-sexp` it confirms that.

When I fire up `M-x describe-key` and try to type `C-)` (that is, press and hold control, press shift, and press `)`) the describer only registers the `)` part and trys to execute `paredit-close-round`.

I know slurp works because if I `M-x paredit-slurp-forward-sexp` it works fine.

Am I not using this hotkey right? It seems like it should be working fine.

Comment: Are you, by any chance, working in terminal Emacs?

Comment: @Dan I am, I am running "emacs -nw". In particular Urxvt with Arch Linux.

Comment: Have a look at [Problems with keybindings when using terminal](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/1020/problems-with-keybindings-when-using-terminal).