# What does S mean in emacs keybinding notation (org-mode)

Tags: org-mode, key-bindings

Looking at the keybindings here http://orgmode.org/guide/Structure-editing.html#Structure-editing, it asks us to use

```
M-S-<RET>
```

to add a TODO at the same level. What does the S here mean? I have tried shift and capital S, neither have worked.

Comment: It does mean shift.  Verify that it's defined with `C-h k` and the keysequence, if it is perhaps something is intercepting the keypress at the operating system level.

Comment: It says I am only doing M-<RET>, so that seems to be the issue. Any pointers on how to get system to stop doing that? I'm using iTerm2 on osX

Comment: Also feel free to add your comment as an answer so I can accept it

Comment: n.b. There are lots of Emacs Q&As about the limited key-sequence support provided by terminals. Here's a recent one with good information and links: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/1020/454

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer. This question still shows up as unanswered. Thx.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "S" means "shift". Since you're using a terminal, you can't type a keyboard shortcut that uses shift unless the shift is modifying a letter (if the shortcut were C-S-j, Emacs would see C-J and know it was the same thing).

Use Emacs outside of your terminal instead, where it has a wider set of capabilities.