# <M-S-return> (org-mode) failing on Windows install

Tags: org-mode, key-bindings, escape

I've just installed Emacs 26.2 on a Windows 7 machine.  This is a clean install, with no previous version of Emacs installed.  Editing an Org file, I want to insert a new TODO item using "M-S-return".  Typing that key sequence results in an error "ESC <return> is undefined."

Since I'm not running in a terminal, the issue doesn't seem to be the terminal eating my keys, as discussed [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/18510/what-does-s-mean-in-emacs-keybinding-notation-org-mode).  Also, C-h l (view-lossage) results in the following:

```
 F [org-self-insert-command]
 o [org-self-insert-command]
 o [org-self-insert-command]
 <escape> <S-return> [nil]
 C-h l [view-lossage]
```

So it appears that the "Shift-return" is making it to emacs.

`C-h m` lists `<M-S-return>` as bound to `org-insert-todo-heading`, as expected.  `C-h k` says `ESC <S-return> (translated from <escape> <S-return>) is undefined`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What does `C-h k` tell you when you use that key sequence? Where is that key sequence defined (in Org, presumably) - can you show the `define-key` (or whatever) sexp that defines it? You write `ret`, but Emacs is telling you it's `<return>` (which makes sense, since you're not using a terminal - it's not `RET`).

Comment: Sorry, "ret" above was an abbreviation on my part.  `C-h m` lists `<M-S-return>` as bound to `org-insert-todo-heading`, as expected.  `C-h k` says `ESC <S-return> (translated from <escape> <S-return>) is undefined`.

Comment: Please put all such info in the question itself. Comments can be deleted at any time. Thx.

Comment: I'm used to using <ESC> as the emacs "Meta" key, and indeed when I run emacs on Windows machines <ESC> generally seems to map to "Meta."  I've just learned that I can also use the "Alt" key as "Meta".   That does seem to work in this case, i.e., "Shift-Alt-Return" runs org-insert-todo-heading, which I can live with.

Comment: Hmm, what key did you expect to be the M? In the emacs manual: [kinds of user input](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/User-Input.html): `We refer to <Alt> as <Meta> for historical reasons`