# Define key chords for windmove

Tags: key-bindings, window, osx, terminal-emacs

I'm following info found on this [link](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/WindMove), but cannot get the desired custom key bindings to work for `windmove`.

Basically, I put the following in my `.emacs` file:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-M-<left>") 'windmove-left)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-M-<right>") 'windmove-right)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-M-<up>") 'windmove-up)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-M-<down>") 'windmove-down)
```

Where my `Control` key is `Ctrl` and my `Meta` key is `Alt`, and I am using `Emacs 24.5.1` on OS X 10.10.5.

While I have two windows in a maximized terminal (`iTerm2`), nothing happens when I press any of the 3-key chords above. Why?

Comment: Maybe these shortcuts are intercepted by the os. `switch workspaces` on linux.

Comment: Use C-h k and press one of the key chords to confirm what emacs is receiving. I bet that the shift is not seen by the terminal protocol. Getting shift to work as a modifier for anything but capital letters over terminals is, kindly, problematic. Not emacs's fault; do a search on this site for terminal modifier keys. You may need to define a 2-step chord for use on terminals.

Comment: Related: [Problems with keybindings when using terminal](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/1020/problems-with-keybindings-when-using-terminal).

Comment: this might interest you: http://sachachua.com/blog/2015/01/emacs-microhabit-switching-windows-windmove-ace-window-ace-jump/?shareadraft=baba27863_54bd285449177