# How to use a Mac's Command key as a Control key?

Tags: key-bindings

I'm new to Emacs, and am using a Mac.  I want the Mac `command` key to act as a `control` key for Emacs.

**How do I do that?**  I tried `(setq mac-command-modifier 'control)`.

Besides, how do I find key variable and local key names in Emacs?  For example: how can I find that `mac-command-modifier` is the command key name?

Comment: It also might be useful to switch your control key and cap lock key to save you fingers all that stretching. Then you can just press cap locks to use emacs commands.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The EmacsWiki node on
[Emacs for Mac OS](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsForMacOS)
will give you advice on a number of OSX-specific issues.  More specific to your question, you can adjust the
[modifier keys](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsForMacOS#toc24)
as you like:

```
mac-function-modifier
mac-control-modifier
mac-command-modifier
mac-option-modifier
mac-right-command-modifier
mac-right-control-modifier
mac-right-option-modifier
```

Aside: you might see these as `ns-` in place of `mac-` in some
places.  The `ns-`, I believe, is referring to
[NeXTSTEP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NeXTSTEP), one of the
sources for OSX.

You should be fine with your setup to make Emacs interpret the
<kbd>command</kbd> key as <kbd>control</kbd>:

```
(setq mac-command-modifier 'control)
```

Put that in your
[`init` file](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html)
and it should take effect the next time you start Emacs.

For keybindings, the first stop is the Emacs manual node on
[Customizing Key Bindings](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Key-Bindings.html).
Another good resource is Mickey Petersen's
[Mastering Key Bindings in Emacs](https://www.masteringemacs.org/article/mastering-key-bindings-emacs).

Comment: Thanks the document link. but for the problem, I'm saved the config and restart emacs,it not works for me. As for `Option` map to `Meta` same the problem, luckily, mac terminal can set `Option` to `Meta` with terminal preference setting. I doubt mac terminal can't simply change the key's map by `setq` sentence.

Comment: @LoranceChen: are you using Emacs with a terminal?  Terminals have special problems in receiving certain key combinations.

Comment: Yes,its spawn on terminal.It seems I need download some GUI emacs.

Comment: @LoranceChen:  for reference, see the discussion in [Problems with keybindings when using terminal](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/1020/problems-with-keybindings-when-using-terminal).

Comment: I'm don't want deep into the terminal like problem yet.At least, it should be notice at MacOS.