# Emacs shortcuts in Mac are worse than in Ubuntu?

Tags: key-bindings, osx

I just moved from Ubuntu to Mac. Maybe I'm wrong but I found the shortcuts in Mac Emacs is harder to use than in ubuntu. Such as I have to frequently use the "Arrow" in Mac to select texts while in Ubuntu I only need to keep my fingers in main area of keyboards. Specifically, I have two questions:

1. How to select all text in a file? In Ubuntu Emacs, the shortcut is `Ctrl-x + h` which does not work in Mac Emacs.
2. Or anyone know how to config the shortcuts in Mac Emacs to be the same in Ubuntu?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Which Emacs are you referring to here? Ctrl-h doesn’t select all text in any Emacs I know

Comment: @patrix Ohh.. there is a typo in my question, it is Ctrl-x h, sorry for the confusion. I have edited the question.

Comment: This might help: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/26616/how-to-use-a-macs-command-key-as-a-control-key

Comment: Are you using Emacs in the terminal? (macOS comes with an old Emacs 22 which runs in the terminal, maybe it's the one you're using?) Try to download one from https://emacsformacos.com/

Comment: Like patrix, I think you need to clarify what you mean by "Mac Emacs".  The default OSX build of Emacs has the same `C-x h` binding as when you build it for MS-DOS, Windows, or GNU/Linux.  Maybe you're using somethin else, like Aquamacs?  Also, I should mention that, as always "which does not work" is not a useful description of what you see.  So like user1238364 I recommend you tell us what `C-h k C-x h` tells you.

Answer (score 4):

I regularly use Emacs in both mac os x and Ubuntu and haven't noticed any differences in keybindings. I use the Emacs available from:

https://emacsformacosx.com/

`C-x h` works the same for me in each. What does it say when you do `C-h k C-x h`?