# Keycode for `Shift + Return` on OS X iterm2

Tags: org-mode, key-bindings, keymap

I'm currently trying to learn org-mode in OS X. And I found there's a keymap `M-S-RET`. But `S-RET` is not recognized in the iTerm2.

- It seems like terminal interpret `S-RET` and `RET` as same.
- iTerm2 can bind a `S-RET` in the GUI preference tab. (PREFERENCE->PROFILE->KEY)
- I can bind `S-RET` and send hex value instead of 13. (13 is keycode for RET) [image]

But I can't find what's the keycode for the `S-RET`. Actually, I think <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> does not exist as keycode. However, there must be some key combination that Emacs uses.

How can I figure it out? Are there any files containing that information?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: this may help you with other keys. https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/40260

Answer (score 5):

`C-c C-x M` is an alternative for `M-S-Ret`

http://orgmode.org/manual/TTY-keys.html#TTY-keys

Answer (score 2):

As Eric notes above, there is an alternative key binding for `M-S-Ret`:

> C-c C-x M is an alternative for M-S-Ret

(More precisely, both are bound to `(org-insert-todo-heading)` in org-mode.)

You can set iTerm2 to send the hex codes corresponding to the alternative key sequence when you press `M-S-Ret`, thereby invoking the same function and behavior.

The required hex codes:

- `C-c` is 0x03
- `C-x` is 0x18
- `M` is 0x4D

Assuming that you are using the Option key as the Meta key on your Mac keyboard, go to iTerm2 Preferences > Profiles > Keys and map `Option-Shift-Return` to send these codes.

[image]

Now, when you press `Option-Shift-Return` (i.e., `M-S-Ret`), iTerm2 sends `C-x C-x M`.

Et voilà.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really a standard escape sequence for <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Return</kbd>. You could say that there are two standards, but each of them is only followed by a small number of terminals:

- libtermkey: `"\e[13;2u"`
- xterm: `"\e[27;2;13~"`

But Emacs only activates them if it can figure out that the current terminal sends them. Since iTerm2 doesn't send them by default, Emacs doesn't activate them.

You might as well use one of these sequences. To activate them unconditionally, put the following code in your init file (this code is from `terminal-init-xterm` in `term/xterm.el`):

```
(load "term/xterm")
(let ((map (copy-keymap xterm-function-map)))
  (set-keymap-parent map (keymap-parent input-decode-map))
  (set-keymap-parent input-decode-map map)))
```

For more information and some explanation of these escape sequences, see [Problems with keybindings when using terminal](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/1020/problems-with-keybindings-when-using-terminal/13957#13957)