# C-C C-SPC not working in RHEL 6.7 GNOME 2.28.2

Tags: key-bindings

The key `C-SPC` is not working in RHEL 6.7 GNOME 2.28.2.

When I try `C-h k` and then hit `C-SPC` I see the following message on the mini-buffer:

```
C-@ is undefined
```

That is, `SPC` is mistaken for `@`.

Comment: Are you using the GUI, or are you using Emacs in a terminal?

Comment: @Dan good catch. The GUI version works fine. It's Emacs in a terminal that mistakenly takes `C-SPC` for `C-@`. So what gives?

Comment: It's a common issue in terminals.  See [Problems with keybindings when using terminal](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/1020/problems-with-keybindings-when-using-terminal).

Comment: @Dan reading your answer I understand that with Emacs 23 this terminal issue cannot be fixed so I *have* to use the GUI version (no Emacs 24 on RHEL 6.7). Correct?

Comment: The simplest solution is to use the GUI, unless you have a compelling need to use the terminal.  If the terminal swallows the keybinding before it ever reaches Emacs, then it's something you need to fix at the terminal level (or possibly switch to a different terminal that doesn't have that problem).   See also [@Gilles' answer](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/13957/253) to the same question that provides a work-around (in reality, it's a better answer insofar as it offers a potential solution).