# Ubuntu Emacs Meta Key problem related to keys

Tags: key-bindings, terminal-emacs, input-method

I'm using emacs 24.5.1 on ubuntu 16.04 on a Vaio x64 pc. earlier I ran the emacs tutorial and got through it completely no problem. Then I started playing with the "replace-string" command and now my Meta key no longer works so SOME but not all key commands. M-f, M-b, M-a and M-e work fine and so does M-x

But when I do M-> or M-< I get the following messages (see below). No amount of C-g'ing or hitting the ESC seems to help. What happened? How do I get out of it? How do I avoid getting back into this? 
Thanks!

*user-error: No M-x tags-search or M-x tags-query-replace in progress [3 times]
Quit [3 times]
completing-read-default: Command attempted to use minibuffer while in minibuffer [2 times]
Quit
completing-read-default: Command attempted to use minibuffer while in minibuffer [2 times]
user-error: There is no default tag*

Comment: Probably: [Problems with keybindings when using terminal](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/1020/problems-with-keybindings-when-using-terminal).

Comment: Are you using emacs in a terminal? If yes, does the problem appear with graphical emacs?

Comment: After pressing `M->`, press `C-h l`. This opens a window with the last few keys you typed. Check what Emacs sees when you press `M->`.