# How to remap shift-arrow in term-mode?

Tags: key-bindings, term

Is there a way to map `Shift-left` or other arrow keys to custom functions in `term-char-mode`?

I tried, but without luck:

```el
(define-key term-mode-map [s-left] 'sandric/term-switch-line-mode)
```

Entering `Shift-left` in my terminal gives `[1;2D`, so I also tried:

```el
(define-key term-mode-map "[1;2D" 'sandric/term-switch-line-mode)
```

But that also does nothing.

Comment: Related: [Problems with keybindings when using terminal](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/1020/problems-with-keybindings-when-using-terminal).

Comment: @Dan Perhaps not; see [my answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/37094/15748).

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to map `Shift-left` or other arrow keys to custom functions in `term-char-mode`?

There is indeed.

> `(define-key term-mode-map [s-left] 'sandric/term-switch-line-mode)`

Two issues here:

1. `term-mode-map` is the keymap used by line mode, whereas char mode uses `term-raw-map`.
2. `[s-left]` (lowercase `s`) corresponds to the [`<Super>` modifier](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Modifier-Keys.html). The `<Shift>` key is abbreviated as an uppercase `S`, as in `(kbd "S-<left>")` or `[S-left]`.

---

So the solution to your problem is likely

```el
(define-key term-raw-map [S-left] #'sandric/term-switch-line-mode)
```