# C-M-% not works in MacOS terminal

Tags: osx, query-replace

I'm fresh to emacs and following [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Query-Replace.html#Query-Replace) to practice Query-Replace operation. But I find it not work at all. Type `C-h l` where it shows `ESC 5` seems my OS swallow some key input or emacs parse input occurred some error.

<del>`S-M-f` also has the problem.</del>

Besides, I'm use `emacs -nw` to open emacs in terminal. In emacs GUI App, `Shift` works well.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Problems with keybindings when using terminal](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/1020/problems-with-keybindings-when-using-terminal).

Comment: `S-M-f` works well somehow now which in emacs as `ESC F` with `C-h l`. But `M-C-%` as `ESC 5` when arrived to emacs.