# how can a command be bound to Ctrl-' or Ctrl-<NUM> in the terminal

Tags: key-bindings

I want to bind a command to `C-'`, `` C-` `` and `C-0` through `C-9` keys. It's not working in the terminal

Is there a way to do so?

Comment: What did you try that didn’t work?

Comment: I'm using `(bind-key* "C-9" 'next-line)` from `use-package`

Comment: If you're running emacs in text mode inside a terminal, that is not likely to be possible, I think. In general, try typing `C-h c` followed by the key you wish to bind to. If the key works at all, you'll see its name and whatever it is bound to in the echo area.

Comment: A valid answer to your question is "yes", so you might want to rephrase it to clarify what you're after.

Comment: @Stefan. got it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
(define-key text-mode-map (kbd "C-9") #'next-line)
```

Or, with `bind-key`:

```
(bind-key (kbd "C-9") #'next-line)
```

Comment: I'm hoping to use it with `bind-key`

Comment: @zcaudate Then you should have said so initially. (Sorry I can't help; I am unfamiliar with that command.)

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen I think it has to do with the fact that it's running inside the terminal. `M-1` works but not `C-1`. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: @zcaudate This is the correct answer to the question you asked, but it sounds like your actual question is https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/1020/problems-with-keybindings-when-using-terminal

Comment: @zcaudate Yes, there is a reason, but it's kind of technical: Briefly, terminal emulators will transmit M-1 as an ESCape character followed by 1 (and similarly for other M-something combinations). But characters like C-f are transmitted like the letter f with the high order bits zeroed, which works fine for control-letter combinations. There isn't a similar convention for other characters combined with the control key, though, so they generally flat out don't work in a terminal.