# binding M-[ causes mouse focus to insert characters

Tags: key-bindings, terminal-emacs, mouse

I have bound `M-[` to backward-paragraph. This causes a problem in terminal mode, whereby every time the mouse enters or leaves the frame (i.e., Emacs gains or loses focus), the characters I and O are inserted in the buffer.

To reproduce:

start vanilla emacs in terminal mode:

```
emacs -nw -Q
```

bind a function to `M-[`:

```
(global-set-key "\M-[" 'backward-paragraph)
```

move the mouse in and out of the Emacs frame.

What I see are the letters I and O inserted in the window. `view-lossage` shows:

```
 ESC [                  ;; backward-paragraph
 O                      ;; self-insert-command
 ESC [                  ;; backward-paragraph
 I                      ;; self-insert-command
 ESC [                  ;; backward-paragraph
 O                      ;; self-insert-command
 ESC [                  ;; backward-paragraph
 I                      ;; self-insert-command
 ESC [                  ;; backward-paragraph
 O                      ;; self-insert-command
 ESC [                  ;; backward-paragraph
 I                      ;; self-insert-command
```

I can still use `M-[` as a keybinding - pressing it causes point to move backward as expected.

Is this a normal deficiency of terminal-mode emacs, or is it a bug?

Emacs version 27.0.50
Debian with i3 window manager
confirmed with gnome-terminal and xterm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a normal deficiency of most terminals. Terminal send escape sequences to represent input events that don't have a corresponding character, such as function keys, “exotic” modifier combinations and mouse events. Most escape sequences start with `ESC [`. Additionally, the meta modifier, for ordinary characters, is encoded as the `ESC` character followed by the base character. So when you press <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>, Emacs sees `ESC [`; when you press e.g. <kbd>Left</kbd>, Emacs sees either `ESC O D` or `ESC [ D` depending on the terminal configuration; and your terminal seems to send `ESC [ I` and `ESC [ O` for mouse enter/leave events.

A few terminals, including xterm, can be configured to use a different, non-backward-compatible encoding of input events that is not ambiguous. See [Problems with keybindings when using terminal](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/1020/problems-with-keybindings-when-using-terminal/13957#13957) for more information including how to set it up in Emacs.

But for most terminals, including gnome-terminal, you're stuck with <kbd>Esc</kbd> being effectively unusable except as a prefix that meta-ifies the next key, and <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> being effectively unusable, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> being undistinguishable from <kbd>Esc</kbd>, etc.

Comment: Ok. I was aware of the general problem with escape keys in terminals, but thrown off by the unexpected interaction with the mouse. The keybinding itself works just fine - pressing `M-[` calls `backward paragraph` without any problem.