# Is it possible to bind CTRL-SHIFT-xxx and CTRL-num combination?

Tags: key-bindings

I'm very new to emacs and essentially came from `vim` where it is not possible to bind `CTRL-num` combination like (CTRL-1, CTRL-2, etc) which as well as `CTRL-SHIFT-xxx` like `CTRL-#` which essentially works as simply `#`.

Is something like this possible in emacs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is perfectly possible to bind C-digit, at least in a "graphical terminal".  In a text terminal, things may be different because the terminal may itself generate characters from a key combo, which then can't be seen by emacs.  See [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/1020/problems-with-keybindings-when-using-terminal) answer for discussion and links.

Actually, `C-0`, `C-1` etc are already bound in the global map, as can be seen with the command `describe-key`:

```
M-x describe-key CTRL 1
```

> C-1 runs the command digit-argument (found in global-map), which is an
>   interactive compiled Lisp function in ‘simple.el’.
>
> It is bound to C-9, C-8, C-7, C-6, C-5, C-4, C-3, C-2, C-1, C-0, ESC
>   0..9, C-M-9, C-M-8, C-M-7, C-M-6, C-M-5, C-M-4, C-M-3, C-M-2, C-M-1,
>   C-M-0.
>
> (digit-argument ARG)
>
> Part of the numeric argument for the next command.
>   C-u following digits or minus sign ends the argument.

You can rebind it, eg:

```
(global-set-key [(control ?1)] 'save-buffer)
```

You can do the same for #:

```
(global-set-key [(control ?#)] 'save-buffer)
```

For information on how to rebind keys, see the elisp manual chapter on [keymaps](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Keymaps.html).

Comment: But see also https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/1020/problems-with-keybindings-when-using-terminal

Comment: @npostavs Ah, yes indeed this is much more complex then, thanks for raising the issue!  For now, I just added a note about that.