# setting C-, and C-. key bindings

Tags: key-bindings

I am unable to set the `C-,` and `C-.` key bindings!

I tried adding the following,

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-,") 'forward-char)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-.") 'forward-char)
```

In various installations of Emacs and instead of moving the cursor forward Emacs would print either the `,` or `.` characters.

`C-h k C-,` reports,

```
, runs the command self-insert-command (found in global-map), which is
an interactive built-in function in ‘C source code’.
```

similar output for `C-.`.

Is it possible to set bindings for `C-,` or `C-.` in Emacs?

Comment: Works fine for me.  Are you, perhaps, using terminal emacs?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problems with keybindings when using terminal](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/1020/problems-with-keybindings-when-using-terminal)