# How do I type … in the TUI?

Tags: key-bindings, emacsclient, terminal-emacs, keyboard

When I call `describe-key` and enter `…` (`Alt Gr` + `.`), it says `M-b runs the command backward-word […]` and `async-shell-command` (bound to `M-&`) is called.

I'm on Linux with Xorg, the terminal emulator is Alacritty, keyboard layout is German. I can enter `…` just fine in nano.

`showkey -a` shows this when I enter `…`:

```bash
$ LC_ALL=C showkey -a

Press any keys - Ctrl-D will terminate this program

…       226 0342 0xe2
        128 0200 0x80
        166 0246 0xa6
^D        4 0004 0x04
```

**Edit: Additional information ↓**

This is what `view-lossage` reports:

```
 M-b                    ;; backward-word
 C-M-@                  ;; mark-sexp
 M-&                    ;; async-shell-command
```

Interestingly, this happens only if I open the file with `emacsclient` without options. When I open the same file with `emacsclient --tty`, `…` is correctly inserted.

Comment: Related: [Problems with keybindings when using terminal](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/1020/253)

Comment: @Dan I don't think the terminal is the problem, see my update above. I also have the same problem with xfce4-terminal and urxvt