# What is the keycode of C-TAB?

Tags: key-bindings, term, keyboard-layout, ascii

iTerm does not send ctrl+tab itself, so I need to configure it myself. I can't figure it what key code ctrl+tab is though.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problems with keybindings when using terminal](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/1020/problems-with-keybindings-when-using-terminal)

Answer (score 1):

1. In iTerm2 profiles, pick the profile you're using, then go to the Keys settings.
2. Click `+` to add a key command. Click and press `Ctrl+Tab`. Then choose the command Send Escape Sequence. Use `[27;5;9~` as the sequence.

Then test this in `emacs -nw -q` by using `C-h k C-tab` to see if it displays `<C-tab>`.