# Xmodmap modifier used for meta

Tags: terminal-emacs

I would like to set my Alt_L to trigger a meta key in emacs.

I've tried using xmodmap to set Alt_L as Mod1, Mod2, Mod3. But in emacs, when i try to type Alt_L + x (expecting M-x) it only prints "x".

I start X server with : `setxkbmap -model pc105 -layout us,fr -option grp:alt_shift_toggle -option caps:none`

When I print the modifiers with `xmodmap -pm` I get :

```
xmodmap:  up to 4 keys per modifier, (keycodes in parentheses):

shift       Shift_L (0x32),  Shift_R (0x3e)
lock      
control     Control_L (0x25),  Control_L (0x42),  Control_R (0x69)
mod1        Alt_L (0x40),  Alt_R (0x6c),  Meta_L (0xcd)
mod2        Num_Lock (0x4d)
mod3      
mod4        Super_L (0x85),  Super_R (0x86),  Super_L (0xce),  Hyper_L (0xcf)
mod5        ISO_Level3_Shift (0x5c),  Mode_switch (0xcb)
```

I feel the problem comes from emacs, not from X keyboard config.

How emacs handles those modifiers ?

**EDIT**: `setxkbmap -query` ouputs when I start X:

```
rules:      evdev                                                                                                                                                                                                   
model:      pc105                                                                                                                                                                                                   
layout:     us,fr                                                                                                                                                                                                   
options:    ctrl:nocaps,grp:alt_shift_toggle
```

Using `xev` when I type Alt_L then x, then release x and release Alt_L I get:

```
KeyPress event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0xc00001,                                                                                                                                                           
    root 0x1d9, subw 0x0, time 5433348, (-2,510), root:(640,512),                                                                                                                                                   
    state 0x0, keycode 64 (keysym 0xffe9, Alt_L), same_screen YES,                                                                                                                                                  
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes:                                                                                                                                                                                    
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes:                                                                                                                                                                                  
    XFilterEvent returns: False                                                                                                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
KeyPress event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0xc00001,                                                                                                                                                           
    root 0x1d9, subw 0x0, time 5438940, (-2,510), root:(640,512),                                                                                                                                                   
    state 0x8, keycode 53 (keysym 0x78, x), same_screen YES,                                                                                                                                                        
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (78) "x"                                                                                                                                                                           
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (78) "x"                                                                                                                                                                         
    XFilterEvent returns: False                                                                                                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
KeyRelease event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0xc00001,                                                                                                                                                         
    root 0x1d9, subw 0x0, time 5439004, (-2,510), root:(640,512),                                                                                                                                                   
    state 0x8, keycode 53 (keysym 0x78, x), same_screen YES,                                                                                                                                                        
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (78) "x"                                                                                                                                                                           
    XFilterEvent returns: False                                                                                                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
KeyRelease event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0xc00001,                                                                                                                                                         
    root 0x1d9, subw 0x0, time 5442460, (-2,510), root:(640,512),                                                                                                                                                   
    state 0x8, keycode 64 (keysym 0xffe9, Alt_L), same_screen YES,                                                                                                                                                  
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes:                                                                                                                                                                                    
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Comment: This question is tagged 'terminal-emacs', are you running 'emacs -nw' or the gui version?

Comment: I'm using emacs -nw, not the gui version

Comment: What does `setxkbmap -query` say? What happens if you don't do anything with either `setxkbmap` or `xmodmap` to begin with? If I start `xterm` and then do `xev` and then press the left `Alt` key and `x` together, `xev` reports four independent events: KeyPress Alt_L, KeyPress x, KeyRelease x, KeyRelease Alt_L. Nevertheless, emacs -Q -nw` synthesizes a `M-x` out of the same combination. So try without anything and edit your question with your findings.

Comment: See also [Problems with keybindings when using terminal](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/1020).

Comment: This sounds like an issue with your terminal, not with emacs. Does M-x work as expected in gui emacs? What terminal are you using?

Comment: Yes actually it seems the problem comes from my terminal, I'm using **xterm**

Comment: What version of `xterm` are you running? I have `XTerm(366)`.  I start  `emacs -Q -nw` in an xterm and `Alt_L x` is recognized as `M-x`. `xmodmap -pm` looks similar to yours (I don't have `Alt_R` in there) and so does `setxkbmap -query`. Can't think of anything else ATM - sorry.

Comment: I have Xterm(367), well thank you anyway !