# C-c C-, not working in SSH terminal but it is bound

Tags: ssh

The function `org-insert-structure-template` is bound to `C-c C-,`. I can confirm that when search that function via `M-x` and seeing the shortcut behind the function name.

But I use Emacs (from Debian 11) in an SSH terminal (on Windows 10).

The second part (`C-,`) has no effect. A assume it is suppresed or interpreted different from the SSH terminal.

Any suggestions how to deal with it and how to deeper diagnose this?

Comment: See https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/1020/problems-with-keybindings-when-using-terminal?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: The link seems relevant but I didn't get it to transform the answer into my context. Maybe it is easier to re-map the keys for `org-insert-structure-template`