# How to redefine key binding for "C-m" without clobbering <return>?

Tags: key-bindings, bind-key.el

I am trying to remap "C-m" but it seems to prevent  from working. It actually seems to make  the same as "C-m". I have no idea why.

I have tried this, which causes the problem:
    (bind-keys :map global-map
           ("C-m" . jump-char-backward)
           ("C-," . jump-char-forward))

And I tried this to fix it, which causes the problem that everywhere (for example on helm completion)  now causes a new line:

```
(bind-keys :map global-map
       ("C-m" . jump-char-backward)
       ("C-," . jump-char-forward)
       ("<return>" . newline))
```

How can I fix this? And what mistakes have I made understanding how remapping keys work?!

Comment: Yes it does! As for a noob like me, how it did wasn't completely obvious, so I'll answer this question myself in case it helps others.

Answer (score 0):

As kindly pointed out, [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/220/how-to-bind-c-i-as-different-from-tab) explains it: C-m and  are equivalent in ASCII so we need to first amend how emacs interprets the key sequence C-m. So this should work:

```
(define-key input-decode-map [?\C-m] [C-m])
(global-set-key (kbd "<C-m>") 'jump-char-backward)
```