# elpy (and evil-mode) do not react on TAB

Tags: python, evil, elpy, tabs

This is my `elpy-config`

```
 1Elpy Configuration                                                                                                                                       
 2                                                                                                                                                         
 3Virtualenv........: None                                                                                                                                 
 4RPC Python........: 3.7.3 (/usr/bin/python3)                                                                                                             
 5Interactive Python: /usr/bin/python3 (/usr/bin/python3)                                                                                                  
 6Emacs.............: 26.1                                                                                                                                 
 7Elpy..............: 1.28.0                                                                                                                               
 8Jedi..............: 0.17.2                                                                                                                               
 9Rope..............: Not found                                                                                                                            
10Autopep8..........: 1.5.3                                                                                                                                
11Yapf..............: Not found                                                                                                                            
12Black.............: Not found                                                                                                                            
13Syntax checker....: flake8 (/usr/local/bin/flake8)
```

It runs on Debian 10.

When typing <kbd>TAB</kbd> nothing happens. No message. No change in the mode line or status line.

Is it default that elpy do not work with <kbd>TAB</kbd> and why?

How can I turn this on?

**EDIT**: I expect 4 empty chars when typing <kbd>TAB</kbd>.

**EDIT2**: `M-x describe-key <kbd>TAB</kbd>` results in

```
TAB (translated from <tab>) runs the command evil-jump-forward (found in
evil-motion-state-map), which is an interactive compiled Lisp function in
‘~/.MyAppData/emacs.d/elpa/evil-20201014.2043/evil-commands.el’.

It is bound to TAB.

(evil-jump-forward &optional COUNT)

Go to newer position in jump list.
To go the other way, press C-o.
```

I have `evil-mode` installed and activated. So there must be a reason why TAB is used by `evil-mode` but do not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is based on this [evil-mode mailinglist post](https://lists.ourproject.org/pipermail/implementations-list/2020-November/002334.html)

**Short answer**: This is expected behavior.

**Long answer**:
In python-mode (and elpy), when you start typing, hitting <kbd>TAB</kbd> will not do anything, presumably preventing you from accidental `TAB` inserts which will trigger errors in Python interpreter. The other way arround <kbd>TAB</kbd> results in a "Tab" (e.g. 4 chars) in cases where it is allowed in python context.

e.g. type this two lines

```
def foo():
     """
```

after hitting <kbd>RET</kbd> the cursor jumps in the next (3rd) line but at the first character/column.
Now you are "allowed" to hit <kbd>TAB</kbd> and it works as expected: A "Tab" (4 empty chars) are inserted.
Hitting <kbd>TAB</kbd> again is like pressing <kbd>BACKSPACE</kbd>: The "Tab" is deleted and the cursor is back at column 1.

However, if you want to insert `TAB` forcefully see the section [Indentation Controlled by Major Mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Mode_002dSpecific-Indent.html) in the emacs-documentation. E.g. setting `(setq tab-always-indent nil)` will force `TAB` to be inserted, but will also adjust other indentation.

However, if you want `vi`-like <kbd>TAB</kbd> behavior with `evil-mode`, python and without too much of TAB science, set this in your init file:

```
(define-key evil-insert-state-map (kbd "TAB") 'tab-to-tab-stop)
```

If you are keen to look further for customization, check [The Ultimate Guide To Indentation in Emacs](https://dougie.io/emacs/indentation/).

Comment: Or you could like, customize `evil-want-C-i-jump` and Evil will stop interfering with TAB completely, exposing you to the mess that configuring indentation is.

Comment: Sorry, but I still do not understand the `evil-want-C-i-jump` thing. I think miss some background/basic knowledge here. Even the docu doesn't help me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but probably one of your minor modes overrides the `TAB` key.

You can find the bound function via `M-x describe-key` and `TAB`. Default should be `indent-for-tab-command`. If it is not, you should find  which minor mode overrides the `TAB` binding (you can probably understand using `describe-key`) and unbind it on the minor-mode keymap or rebind `TAB` to `indent-for-tab-command`.

ex: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14316669/7216840

Comment: Thanks for your hint. I updated my question with new information's.

Answer (score -1):

Evil faithfully emulates Vim, including the part of `C-i` and `C-o` being bound in normal state to commands going through the jump list.  `C-i` happens to be equivalent to `TAB` for reasons (hello terminals), so another thing you'll observe is it being bound in insert state to something else, like an indentation command.  If you dislike that behavior, you've got two options:

- Disable binding `C-i` at all by customizing `evil-want-C-i-jump`.
- Have both by using GUI Emacs and this hack: [How to bind C-i as different from TAB?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/220/how-to-bind-c-i-as-different-from-tab)

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand anything.

Comment: If you don't understand what normal/insert states are, I recommend reading Evil's manual first.

Comment: I understand the vi-states of course. Using `vim` science over 20 years. I do not see the logic behind `C-i` and `TAB`.

Comment: OK, so you do understand that part at least. `C-i` and `TAB` are considered the same in terminals and Emacs pretends it's running in one, even when in graphical mode. See http://catern.com/posts/terminal_quirks.html and https://garbagecollected.org/2017/01/31/four-column-ascii/ for a detailed explanation of the former.