# How to remap org-capture-templates keybindings?

Tags: org-mode, key-bindings, org-capture

I mapped `org-capture` with `C-c c` like this:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c c") #'org-capture)
```

Amongst my `org-capture-template`, two have been set like this:

```
 ("i" "Inbox"
       entry (file+datetree ,(concat captures-path "inbox.org"))
       "* INBOX %?")
  
 ("j" "Journal Entry for tmp"
       entry (file+datetree ,(concat captures-path "jtmp.org"))
       "* %?" :empty-lines 1)
```

Since I use a lot these two, I would like to remap them respectively with `C-i` and `C-j` (Which are duplicates of `TAB` and `RET`). All my attempts failed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things going on here:

1. How to open a particular template from lisp
2. How to bind a function to `C-i`.

For the first, note that `org-capture` takes an optional argument to set the template.

For the second, you need to override the translation to `TAB`: see this [question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/220/how-to-bind-c-i-as-different-from-tab) for that.

Putting this together gives:

```lisp
(define-key input-decode-map [?\C-i] [C-i])
(global-set-key (kbd "<C-i>") 
                (lambda () "Open inbox capture window"
                    (interactive)
                    (org-capture nil "i")))
```